# Internet suddenly very slow on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wireless, 20.04, usb, docker

My Ubuntu system is suddenly having very slow internet - which is not an ISP issue since my other devices are having the expected internet speed.

Running **fast** command, I get like 1.67 Mbps (compared to that I had over 300 Mbps before)

I'm using a USB WiFi device:

```
lsusb: Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0846:9053 NetGear, Inc. A6210
```

**iwconfig** shows:

```
lo no wireless extensions.


eno1 no wireless extensions.


wlx9cc9eb2cc71e IEEE 802.11 ESSID:"Elekko"

Mode:Managed Frequency:2.447 GHz Access Point: D4:5D:64:D9:1A:30

Bit Rate=144.4 Mb/s Tx-Power=18 dBm

Retry short limit:7 RTS thr:off Fragment thr:off

Power Management:off

Link Quality=56/70 Signal level=-54 dBm

Rx invalid nwid:0 Rx invalid crypt:0 Rx invalid frag:0

Tx excessive retries:86 Invalid misc:105 Missed beacon:0


docker0 no wireless extensions.
```

Im suspecting that this MIGHT have happened after I installed docker on my computer since I see docker0 interface in iwconfig.

I don't have any docker containers running.

docker ps and docker ps --all are all empty.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Sincerely

Comment: Start with the obvious: Uninstall Docker. Reboot your system. Reboot your router. Then test your speed again.

Comment: Seems that does not help, I have completely uninstalled, rebooted and still having issues with this.